# Properly encrypt using AES-256 in CBC mode?

Tags: cryptography, aes

For the purpose of the tool I am [currently writing](https://github.com/tehmoon/cryptocli), I need to perform some AES encryption/decryption on some input. It's like a pipeline: you feed it data, it runs the algorithm and pass it out to the next modifier.

I'm used to `openssl enc -aes-256-cbc` to encrypt and decrypt everything. My understanding of this is, it first derive the key you enter using some kind of `pbkdf-sha1` with some 8 bytes generated `salt`, then derive the `iv` from the `derived key + salt`.

It obviously only works with OpenSSL since I wasn't able to find any standard regarding how to communicate – or write to file – the `iv` and `salt` parameters. I was expecting some kind of RFC (like for elliptic curve parameters) but no luck.

My idea is to have a 64 bytes header: `salt + iv` first in the file, then it is followed by the encrypted data. I will use the `salt` with `pbkdf2-sha256` to derive the key.

The headers don't have a fixed length, adjusting the right parameters when you start the program will get the `salt` and `iv` set to the right values.

I don't want to make no mistake. I was amazed how it could be the weakest link and how easy it is to recover a password from a bad key derivation and/or IV generation.

I am pretty sure every aes implementation rolls their own protocol on parameters. And I think it is sad.

I will of course be using `crypto/aes` from Go and their `pbkdf2`, always taking the random source from `crypto/rand` and not `math/rand`.

To sum up:

- Is there any standard on having AES parameters like `salt` and `iv`?
- Should I generate the `iv` or derive it from the `salt || dk`?

**EDIT**

I forgot to mention that I was going to use `PKCS 5#2.0` which specify how to derive the key, but this question was more towards best practices on the `iv` and `salt` storing for broader compatibility.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, the `salt` is not an AES parameter. You have two different primitives here:

You would have:

- `pbkdf(salt, password)` returns `aes_key`
- `aes(iv, aes_key)`

The IV size should match the block size you are using (typically 128-bit as that's the one standarised, although [other block sizes are possible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard#cite_note-blocksize-2)).

Generate a new, random, iv for each file you want to encrypt.

Every AES implementation **must** provide the same algorithm. The *way you choose to save data on disk* is what differs.

A common solution would be to simply append everything:

```
file_password_salt || file_iv || file_contents
```

However, a more future-proof solution would embed some parameter pointing to the size of the fields and the algorithm used. Or, at least, a version number (eg. v1 PBKDF1 with SHA1 and AES-128, in a few months you may want to use Argon, with Camellia…).

Then, you could decide to use a format already used by other tools, so that it is compatible with them. For example copying what OpenSSL does (see that "SALTED" string?), or making it output a zip wrapper over the aes content.

Comment: I see, yes you are right. I've looked at that "Salted" string but it appeared to just be a trick to be backward compatible with the `--nosalt` option. I also looked at `PKCS 5#2.1`.


So I am going to append everything to file since it is secure. Also rework on the question.

One more thing, is it better to derive the iv from the `salt || dk`? The only benefit I see is to save space, but realistically speaking, it's not that long.
Thank you for the response though.

Comment: @tehmoon Generate a new, random iv. The iv **must** be unique. Given that you generate a proper random salt per file, it could be acceptable to derive it and hope that don't enable a related key attack somehow. But it's much easier to be on the safe side and simply generate a new iv.

Comment: AES128,192,256 are _key_ sizes; the _data_ block size and thus IV size for most modes including CBC is _always_ 128 bits = 16 octets. _Rijndael_ does support other block sizes, but they are not standard and as a result are not widely implemented or interoperable.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 thanks. Indeed only iv size matters , as the key size is derived through pbkdf. I have edited the answer to clarify this.

Answer (score 2):

Near cross-dupe https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/27444/standard-format-to-encode-aes-cipher-and-random-iv

`openssl enc` derives both key and IV from pw and salt, based on but modified from PKCS5 **v1**, see (my) https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/3298/is-there-a-standard-for-openssl-interoperable-aes-encryption -- but don't take that as an example to follow.

In addition to ASN.1-based CMS, which is several RFCs (see link above), OpenPGP format (using its own encoding) supports password-based encryption and is [RFC 4880](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4880), and the standards for XML encryption and signature are published by w3.org in an open process similar to RFCs but not under IETF. Both PKCS7/CMS and PGP were originally designed for public-key encryption (really hybrid public-key plus symmetric) and public-key signature (ditto), but options for password-based (plus symmetric) encryption were added.

If you need pipeline/streaming operation it will be harder to add (or include) authentication, very likely leaving you open to active attacks.

Comment: Please, [don't choose XML as your encryption format](https://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/~pgut001/pubs/xmlsec.txt)!

Comment: @Ángel: I don't particularly recommend XMLenc/dsig, or indeed XML for anything, but the question _is_ 'standard ... how to communicate [encryption] parameters'. OTOH according to Gutmann X.509 certs are also totally impossible to implement and no one in the world will ever be able to make an HTTPS connection. Do you know of anyone who has made an HTTPS connection? For example, has anybody connected to any Stack site in the last year or so?